# Xperia Z2 D6502 can't reboot into recovery

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp, sony-xperia-z2

I've searched everywhere, from XDA to Android Enthusiasts and hit a deadend every time. I have a rooted 17.1.2.A.0.314 Kitkat based Xperia Z2. I downgraded the firmware to root it so that I could install a pre-rooted version of the latest Marshmallow ROM via recovery..which doesn't work.
I installed [XZDualRecovery](http://nut.xperia-files.com/path/XZDualRecovery) and later TWRP but when I trigger a reboot to recovery, it doesn't work and the phone restarts normally.

I have tried the button press combos (press volume down during bootup when the light is red, use `adb` and `fastboot`,use the NDRUtils app to trigger reboot to recovery..nothing works.

What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing question with my own answer, posted in comment above - I used [Flashfire](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.flash) and was able to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using apps to reboot into Recovery. For example [**QuickBoot**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.siriusapplications.quickboot)

Comment: Ended up using Flashfire eventually.